# Magento2 set a price to configurable products depends on attribute

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, configurable-product, product-attribute, price

I have created a configurable products on my `magento2` website. Now I have to set the price for associated products. I know how to set the price for single single attribute value but I need to set the price for combinations of attribute value.

for e.g. I have 3 attributes Size, Fabrics & Color. Now I want to set the price for combinations of Size and color. this facility not provided my magento. I have searched for custom functionality but know solution found. Anyone please help me to fix this issue. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

The price calculation is done for the configurable products as below and you should be able to use the OOB solution.

You created many simple products and set the price respectively for each simple products.

```
SKU, Size, Fabrics, Color, Price
SKU1, 10, Silk, Red, 100
SKU1-2, 10, Silk, Blue, 150
SKU2, 11, Silk, Blue, 200
SKU3, 12, Silk, Black, 300
SKU4, 13, Silk, White, 400
```

And you created a configurable product using the attributes and the price will reflect based on the color, size and fabrics selection.

Please provide more details if you expect some other output. Provide some examples